# Firebase auth function runs twice. Vue js

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

when create user with Firebase createUserWithEmailAndPassword. Function runs twice. That's why, it gives error that email is already in use. App in vue js 2 and firebase 9.

```js
async registerForm(){
    const auth = getAuth()
    const user = await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, this.email, this.password)
        .then(userCredential => {
            this.userId = userCredential.user.uid
            console.log(this.userId);
            this.x++
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    console.log('user signed up', this.x);
    this.$router.replace({name: 'home'})**
}
```

Comment: Looking at the code there is no reason to have it running twice. The problem is probably somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

The problem maybe in the routing redirect, if you have located the auth function on the rendering side, when you change the route or move to another one you are rendering again the component which could be a reason to call the function twice